# How to test and bechmark POA consensus?

Tags: blockchain, consensus, poa

How test POA consusus that only authorized sealer can seal the block. How to run test cases ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if thats what you are looking for (try to be more explicit on your questions).

But as far as I understood, to test a PoA consensus yo have this options:

- Kovan (The official PoA testnet) where you can test your contracts or whatever you want.
- If you want to test how the PoA consensus works and create a private PoA ethereum blockchain, you can do it with [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth).

Here you have a link to a post that explains quite good how to create a PoA blockchain: https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have setup PoA consensus engine in private ethereum network 
I want to perfom some test to PoA consensus engine. How can I perform test ?

Comment: By making the changes you want to the consensus algorithm, building the blockchain, and realize actions that let you check if the PoA algorithm is doing what you expect. I don't understand what's the problem. The testing is performed when you run the blockchain nodes and look what's happening vs. what you expected will happen.